# Compactness of a set in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

> Consider $$A=\Big\{(z_1,z_2) \in \Bbb{C}^2 : z_1^2+z_2^2=1\Big\}$$
>
> Is $A$ compact?

My try:  If $A$ is compact, then it is closed and bounded

But it is not bounded! Since $(n,\sqrt{1-n^2});n\in \Bbb{N}$ satisfies this and $\Bbb{N}$ is unbounded. So not compact.

Am I right? If not, any help?

Comment: In a competition, this question would be confusing since the corresponding equation in $\mathbb R^2$ corresponds to a compact set.You are right, this set is unbounded, hence definitely not compact.

Comment: complex analysis tag may be needed instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally dislike the use of the square root sign in this context (it stops being well-defined the moment you start using it on negative numbers), but that may be fixed by writing, say, $(n, i\sqrt{n^2-1})$ instead. However, not everyone are as opposed to writing $\sqrt{-1}$ as I am.

Apart from that it looks good. Well done!

Comment: @LDM Then you (and probably your teacher and / or textbook) are not as opposed to the idea as I am. I think it is not well-defined but I realize there are other conventions. Just be advised that rules you have learned, like $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$, stops working in that case.

Comment: Ok! I understand! Thank you sir

Comment: Good remark.( +1)